# How to use GitHub SSH key for private/public repositories in a Nodejs for (clone, pull, push, and commit)

Tags: node.js, github, nodegit, node-github

I tried using Nodegit in the same method, but I got an error message saying "Clone.clone, stack: Error: Method clone has caused an error." or "Github authentitation failed."

I have tried it but it gives me below error message

> Error: Method clone has thrown an error. {errno: -1, errorFunction:
> 'Clone.clone', stack: 'Error: Method clone has thrown an error.',
> message: 'Method clone has thrown an error.'}

```
class GitClient {
    constructor(realname, email, token, username, repoName, branch, local) {
        this.config = {
            branch,
            remote: "SSH URL",
            local,
            username,
            realname,
            email,
            token
        };
        this.cloneOpts = {
            callbacks: {
                certificateCheck: () => { return 0; },
                credentials: (url, username) => {
                    return NodeGit.Cred.sshKeyNew(
                        username,
                        path.join(this.config.local, '.ssh/id_rsa.pub'),
                        path.join(this.config.local, '.ssh/id_rsa'),
                        ''
                    );
                    // return NodeGit.Cred.sshKeyFromAgent(username);
                }
            }
        };
        this.cloneOpts.fetchOpts = { callbacks: this.cloneOpts.callbacks };
    }

    async clone(options) {
        this.cloneOpts.checkoutBranch = options.branch;
        return NodeGit.Clone(options.remote, options.local, this.cloneOpts).then((data) => {
            console.log(data)
            return data;
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your code, and on the type of SSH keys used.

If you are using OpenSSH one, as shown in [`nodegit/nodegit` issue 1594](https://github.com/nodegit/nodegit/issues/1594#issuecomment-557109998), then it should work with:

```js
const Git = require('nodegit');

const cloneURL = "git@URL:PATH_TO_GIT.git";
var local_publickey = local("/ssh/ssh-public-manual.pub");
var local_privatekey = local("/ssh/openssh-private-key");
var tmpGitPath = "./tmp";

var opts = {
    fetchOpts: {
        callbacks: {
            certificateCheck: () => 0,
            credentials: function(url, userName) {
                return Git.Cred.sshKeyNew(
                    userName,
                    local_publickey,
                    local_privatekey,
                    "SECRET_OF_PRIVATE_KEY"
                );
            }
        }
    }
};

Git.Clone.clone(cloneURL,tmpGitPath,opts)
    .then(function(repo) {
        if(repo instanceof Git.Repository) {
            console.log("Good!");
        } else {
            console.log("Bad!");
        }
        console.log('Cloning DONE');
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
        console.log('/!\\ ERROR /!\\');
        console.log(err);
    });
```

Comment: I have tried the same thing but it gives me below error message 

`Error: Method clone has thrown an error. {errno: -1, errorFunction: 'Clone.clone', stack: 'Error: Method clone has thrown an error.', message: 'Method clone has thrown an error.'}`

Comment: @NiravChauhan Is a manual `ssh -Tv git@github.com` working? (outside of any program, directly in command-line)

Comment: Yes it gave me 
`You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.`

Now I am able to successfully clone the REPO using above code actually path that I had given was wrong.
Thanks @VonC

Comment: One more question,
Which is the method to generate those keys programmatically in Nodejs and use it in Git.Cred.sshKeyNew() (file path - public and private) function
for above code I have added it manually using command line 
now I want to do it using **NODEJS**

Comment: Sure,
So what I need here is to generate public and private keys and save them to a local file so I can use them in Git.Cred.sshKeyNew() function for filepath

Comment: @NiravChauhan You would need https://www.npmjs.com/package/ssh-keygen + https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/users#create-a-public-ssh-key-for-the-authenticated-user (to register the public key to the user profile), or call [`gh ssh-key add`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_ssh-key_add) from node, assuming you have installed the `gh` cli.

Comment: Great help ! Thanks
As per Github 
[link](https://github.blog/2021-09-01-improving-git-protocol-security-github/)
So how can we use **ed2551** instead of RSA

Comment: @NiravChauhan Good point, I agree. I mentioned that (ed25519) in https://stackoverflow.com/a/70767367/6309, and https://stackoverflow.com/a/65370706/6309, but mostly in https://stackoverflow.com/a/70734156/6309.

Comment: I tried ssh-keygen npm package to generate keys But it gives me below output.
_Keys created!_
_private key: undefined_
_public key: undefined_

Comment: @NiravChauhan That would be better addressed in a separate question, with a more complete and detailed error output.

Comment: Sure 
kindly refer
[ssh-keygen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71657784/ssh-keygen-npm-package-gives-undefined-public-and-private-keys)