# ssh-keygen npm package gives undefined public and private keys

Tags: javascript, npm, ssh-keygen

Output for the keys is undefined for both private and public key
[ssh-keygen][1]

> Keys created!
>
> private key: undefined
> public key: undefined

```
async generateAndWriteSSHKeyv2() {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    let t = new Date().getTime();
    var location = path.join(process.cwd(), `contents/apps/SSHkeys/key_${t}`);
    var comment = 'test';
    var password = 'test';
    var format = 'PEM';
    keygen({
        location: location,
        comment: comment,
        password: password,
        read: true,
        destroy: false,
        format: format,
        size: 4096,
    }, (err, output) => {
        if (err) resolve(console.log('Something went wrong: ' + err));
        console.log('Keys created!');
        console.log('private key: ' + output.key);
        console.log('public key: ' + output.pubKey);
        resolve({
            location,
            comment,
            password,
            read: true,
            format,
            size: 4096,
            output
        })
    });
})
};
```

Comment: Can you add some context, as the npm version, and where you do execute this? (in a GitHub Action/workflow? Or on your PC? With which OS/version?)

Comment: npm -v **6.14.6**
node -v  **v12.18.3**
OS:  windows 10
Using mentioned (NodeJS) function to generate SSH key for github Account Auth process to access Repo

Answer (score 0):

I have found [this example](https://github.com/784134748/rest-server/blob/4f7dbb6aabe77a95c301cd95b5ee1baf77dfe070/src/models/job.js#L505-L518), for you to compare with your own code

```js
  generateSshKeyFiles(name, next) {
    keygen({
      location: name,
      read: true,
      destroy: true,
    }, function(err, out) {
      if (err) {
        next(err);
      } else {
        let sshKeyFiles = [{'content': out.pubKey, 'fileName': name+'.pub'}, {'content': out.key, 'fileName': name}];
        next(null, sshKeyFiles);
      }
    });
  }
```

Check if you get the same kind of error message with that type of function.

Comment: This also Giving the same error

Comment: I also tried it using "child_process" to execute SSH_KEYGEN command, which gives me  "command is not recognized as a internal or  external command"
is there any alternative that you can suggest

Comment: @NiravChauhan Mainly to check what user is running this process, and what $HOME is, because ssh-keygen is based on $HOME/.ssh/ folder.